# 2 Inner join in the same table with 1 Optional Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect my `UserAccount` table to itself.

CreatedBy = UserId to produce `CreatedByName`

ModifiedBy = UserId but this is nullable to produce `ModifiedByName`

Here's my query

```
SELECT b.UserId, b.Username, b.Name, b.CreatedBy, a.Name as CreatedByName, b.ModifiedBy, b.ModifiedDate from UserAccount
INNER JOIN UserAccount a ON a.CreatedBy = UserAccount.UserId
RIGHT OUTER JOIN UserAccount b ON b.ModifiedBy = a.UserId
```

But this query can only get the join of ModifiedByName but it cannot get the CreatedByName

Here's the column:

1. UserId (int)
2. Name (nvarchar)
3. CreatedBy (int)
4. ModifiedBy (int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `LEFT JOIN`s for both joins -- in case either name is missing.

Also, using table aliases that represent the tables makes the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT ua.*, uac.Name as CreatedByName, uam.Name as ModfiedByName
FROM UserAccount ua LEFT JOIN
     UserAccount uac
     ON ua.CreatedBy = uac.UserId LEFT JOIN 
     UserAccount uam
     ON ua.ModifiedBy = uam.UserId;
```